# Render Items while .map() function is running

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

I have a large list of items in my React App. Generally I have 2000 items but they don't render until the map finishes.
[image: This is the code]

So in this code, when the map starts running, the loader stops animating because props.items.length is greater than one, but the map take a while to finish so the elements don't show.

Someone knows how to fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Break your component load into smaller chunks... Say, load first 20. Then in background load more. Life infinity loading. I doubt viewport can handle all 2000 items at 1 go. So only load items that viewport can load and then load remaining in batches

Comment: You want to use a library that does. list virtualisation for example https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window

Comment: If you care about performance a lot, you could also move things like that mapping function to a separate thread.

Comment: @Kielstra how could I move that to a separate thread? Because is very important the performance in this case

Comment: @FranViau You want to look into web workers: https://medium.com/techtrument/multithreading-javascript-46156179cf9a. Note that anything that updates the DOM needs to happen from the main thread.

Comment: @Kielstra In this case I don't think I am able to run a .map() function in another thread because the elements returned ar DOM elements

Comment: @FranViau Good point, sorry. Then the solution above of doing it in smaller chunks is a good idea.